# Backup Minecraft SMP Server Seed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the best way to backup the seed of a minecraft server? I'm getting ready to set up a "permanent" world after the full minecraft version is released, and I want to do everything possible to prevent both world block corruption and world seed corruption.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't your spawn be different if you restore a map with just a seed?  Besides, seeds are just numbers.  Store it in a text file or something.

Comment: I want to be able to restore the seed so the server won't get the "fail cliffs" where the seed get corrupted whenever the server crashes. I already have tools to move the spawn, but the seed is a different story. =)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense to me. The abrupt terrain transitions and biome corruptions are caused by the terrain generator being changed with an update. If you generate a new map using the same seed, it'll be completely different.

Comment: @lunboks is correct.  In my SSP game, the value of the seed hasn't changed, yet because it's been through numerous updates, my world has some abrupt edges.  2 worlds generated with the same seed, one from 1.4 say and the other from 1.9 won't look anything alike, even neglecting things like biomes and NPC villages.

Comment: @MBraedley, I have many cliffs of mojang or whatever you would like to call them in my current world, but I don't recall whether that occurred between versions of the game or not as I wasn't doing the exploring. For now I'll take his word for it. =)

Comment: @lunboks In SMP the seed value frequently gets lost from the level.dat if it's not written right and will generate a new one.  This has been an SMP problem from day one.  Setting it in the server.properties is a recent addition and seems to help, but is no guarantee.  You also get the cliffs when terrain generator changes, but SMP resets the seed value often enough that I can assure you it's not just for terrain generator updates (have had it reset more than once in a 24 hour period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seed is just a number in the server.properties file.  You can see the seed value of the world in the client now, and when you set up a permanent server, add it into there so you dont get the cliffs of mojang when generating new chunks.